# Prove that an irrotational vector field is conservative by showing the $\nabla$ of the scalar potential of $v$ written as an integral is equal to $v$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, scalar-fields

I am trying to prove that if $\vec v$ is a continuously differentiable vector field define on $\mathbb R^n$ and satisfies

$$\frac {\partial v_i} {\partial x_j} = \frac {\partial v_j} {\partial x_i}$$

then $\nabla f(x) = \vec v(x)$ where $f(x) = \int_0^1 x \cdot \vec v(tx) \, \mathrm d t$.

This is my attempt: It suffices to prove $v_i(x) = \frac {\partial f(x)} {\partial x_i}$.

I shall use implicit summation over $j$ here when I apply the chain rule. I first use the fundamental theorem of calculus: $$\begin{align} v_i(x) & = \int _0^1  \frac {\partial v_i(tx)} {\partial t}\, \mathrm d t + v_i(0) \\ & = \int_0^1 \frac {\partial v_i(tx)} {\partial x_j} \frac {\partial x_j} {\partial t}\, \mathrm d t + v_i(0) \\ & = \int_0^1 \frac {\partial v_j(tx)} {\partial x_i}  \frac {\partial x_j} {\partial t}\, \mathrm d t + v_i(0) \end{align}$$

I shall also use implicit summation over $j$ here when I expand out the dot product: $$\begin{align} \frac {\partial f(x)} {\partial x_i} & = \int_0^1 \frac {\partial } {\partial x_i} \left( x_j v_j(tx)\right) \, \mathrm d t \\ & = \int_0^1 v_i(tx) + x_j \frac {\partial v_j(tx)} {\partial x_i}\, \mathrm d t\end{align}$$

I am rather stuck here though and not sure how to proceed. Any hints would be appreciated. Have I made any mistakes so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You drop a *t* taking a partial derivative. The derivation goes like this:

$\begin{align} 
\frac {\partial f(x)} {\partial x_i} & = \int_0^1 \frac {\partial } {\partial x_i} \left( x_j v_j(tx)\right) \, \mathrm d t \\ 
& = \int_0^1 v_i(tx) + x_j \frac {\partial} {\partial x_i}[v_j(tx)]\, \mathrm d t = 
\int_0^1 v_i(tx) + x_j \frac {\partial v_j} {\partial x_i}(tx)*t \,\, \mathrm d t  \\
& = \int_0^1 v_i(tx) + t\,x_j \frac {\partial v_i} {\partial x_j}(tx)\, \mathrm d t  \\
& = \int_0^1 v_i(tx) + t \ \frac{d}{dt} [v_i(tx)]\, \mathrm d t = 
\int_0^1  \frac{d}{dt} [t \ v_i(tx)]\, \mathrm d t
\\
& = \ \ t \ v_i(tx)\Big{|}_0^1  = v_i(x)\\
\end{align}$

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you please kindly elaborate on how you got from line 3 to the beginning of line 4? Don't you need $\frac {dx_j} {dt}$ to use the chain rule not just $x_j$?

Comment: $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}[v_j(t\ x_1,..., t\ x_i, ..., t\ x_n )] = \\
\frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_i}(t\ x_1,..., t\ x_i, ..., t\ x_n ) \frac{\partial (t\ x_i)}{\partial x_i} = \\
\frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_i}(t\ x_1,..., t\ x_i, ..., t\ x_n ) \ t$

Comment: I understand that part. The part I am unsure about is line 3 to line 4. I.e. why is $$x_j \frac{\partial v_i} {\partial x_j} (tx) = \frac {\mathrm d} {\mathrm d t} [ v_i(tx)]$$ Thank you very much

Comment: chain rule!  
$\frac{d}{dt}[v_i(t\ x)] = \sum_j \frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j}(.., t\ x_j,..) \frac{d}{dt}(t\ x_j) =   \sum_j \frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j}(.., t\ x_j,..) \  x_j$